# getelementbyid within a div

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I should note that all my script is in a separate file to my HTML

Using document.getElementById, I can successfully alter any element that is directly within the body element, but I cannot select an element that is within another element.
For example:

```
<body>
<div id="example">
<p id="examplep"> Blah Blah Blah </p>
</div>
</body>
```

my Javascript

```
var function1 = function() {
document.getElementById("example").style.color = 'black'
}

var function2 = function() {
document.getElementById("examplep").innerhtml = "Bluh Bluh Bluh"
}
```

function1 would work, but function2 would not, I've tried using firstchild, i've tried renaming, but none of it works.

Comment: That's because it's case sensitive. It's `innerHTML`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
document.getElementById("examplep").innerText= "Bluh Bluh Bluh"
```

Comment: You could use innerText if you're sure that only text should be set.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is case sensitive language. There are [`innerHTML`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) function, but not `innerhtml`.

Change this:

```
var function2 = function() {
document.getElementById("examplep").innerhtml = "Bluh Bluh Bluh"
}
```

To this:

```
var function2 = function() {
    document.getElementById("examplep").innerHTML = "Bluh Bluh Bluh"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
document.getElementById("examplep").innerhtml = "Bluh Bluh Bluh"
```

to

```
document.getElementById("examplep").innerHTML = "Bluh Bluh Bluh"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this code

```
var function2 = function() {
   document.getElementById("examplep").innerhtml = "Bluh Bluh Bluh"
}
```

To this:

```
var function2 = function() {
   document.getElementById("examplep").innerHTML = "Bluh Bluh Bluh";
};
```

This is because javascript and jQuery are case censitive.